# MDX and PieChart

Tags: mdx, pie-chart, dashboard

I'm trying to display a PieChart on using Community Dashboard Framework with this simple query:

```
with member [Measures].[ContaComp] as 
'Iif(IsEmpty([Measures].[COUNT_COMPONENTI]), 0, [Measures].[COUNT_COMPONENTI])' 
select NON EMPTY {[Measures].[ContaComp]} ON COLUMNS,
{DIM_SESSO.All, DIM_SESSO.M, DIM_SESSO.F} on 1
from anagrafe
WHERE DIM_STATO_RECORD.A
```

which returns this dataset:

```
Axis #0:
{[DIM_STATO_RECORD].[A]}
Axis #1:
{[Measures].[ContaComp]}
Axis #2:
{[DIM_SESSO].[ALL]}
{[DIM_SESSO].[M]}
{[DIM_SESSO].[F]}
Row #0: 2.145
Row #1: 1.011
Row #2: 1.134
```

What I'm wrong? Nothing appears on the chart componet.... even if  about me this dataset is ok to display in a pie chart, isn't it?

What is the difference respect to the following mdx query which works?

```
select NON EMPTY {[Measures].[count]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY {[DIM_LOCALITA.LOCALITA].[X].Children} ON ROWS 
from [Pratiche] 
where ([DIM_STATO_RECORD].[A], [DIM_TIPO_PRATICA].[RS])
```

and rerturns the following dataset, which is similar to the previous one?

```
Axis #0:
{[DIM_STATO_RECORD].[A], [DIM_TIPO_PRATICA].[RSA13]}
Axis #1:
{[Measures].[COUNT_PRATICHE]}
Axis #2:
{[DIM_LOCALITA.LOCALITA].[X].[X1]}
{[DIM_LOCALITA.LOCALITA].[X].[X2]}
{[DIM_LOCALITA.LOCALITA].[X].[X3]}
{[DIM_LOCALITA.LOCALITA].[X].[X4]}
{[DIM_LOCALITA.LOCALITA].[X].[X5]}
{[DIM_LOCALITA.LOCALITA].[X].[X6]}
{[DIM_LOCALITA.LOCALITA].[X].[X7]}
{[DIM_LOCALITA.LOCALITA].[X].[X8]}
{[DIM_LOCALITA.LOCALITA].[X].[X9]}
{[DIM_LOCALITA.LOCALITA].[X].[X10]}
Row #0: 15
Row #1: 11
Row #2: 180
Row #3: 74
Row #4: 67
Row #5: 3.063
Row #6: 13
Row #7: 55
Row #8: 20
Row #9: 321
```